# How would I set a specific color role's color of a QPalette to that of another QPalette's color role's color in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt

What I have on hand are two widgets, one of which's bg color I'd like to be set as the text color of the other. After going through the docs, I couldn't find any method that'd yield me the color of a specific color role from a palette.

The closest method in terms of relevancy simply returns a QBrush `QPalette.colorRole`, which I don't see as to how it can help here.

Say I had something of the form

```py
widget1 = QWidget()
palette1 = widget1.palette()
palette1.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor('#FFAABBCC'))
widget1.setPalette(palette1)

widget2 = QWigdet()
palette2 = widget2.palette()
palette2.setColor(widget1s text color) #assume this is what the command tries to do
```

I'd like for a way to set `palette2`'s `QPalette.Base` color role for instance, to be set to the same color as `palette1`'s `QPalette.Text` role. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While QPalette accepts QColors, its roles are all based on QBrush; unless the brush uses a gradient or an image, the brush [`color()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#color) will return a valid QColor.

Setting the color of another role is as simple as [`setColor(role, color)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setColor-1).

Since you are already using palettes, it's not necessary to pass through the color, and you can just assign the original brush with [`setBrush(role, brush)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setBrush):

```
widget1 = QWidget()
palette1 = widget1.palette()
palette1.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor('#FFAABBCC'))
widget1.setPalette(palette1)

widget2 = QWigdet()
palette2 = widget2.palette()
palette2.setBrush(QPalette.Base, palette1.brush(QPalette.Text))
# alternatively
palette2.setBrush(QPalette.Base, palette1.text())

widget2.setPalette(palette2)
```

The direct getter functions (like `text()` or `window()`) always return a QBrush and they are shortcuts to `brush(role)` for the current *color group*. Whenever you need to specify different color groups, you have to use the appropriate `brush()`/`color()` and `setBrush()`/`setColor()` functions that accept the group, otherwise use `setCurrentColorGroup()` before that if you need multiple calls on the same group.